# Градиентная дуга определённого размера

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, знающие люди, как сделать такую дугу?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ничего не приходит в голову, кроме бордера, но им нельзя сделать градиент + он сужается к краям

Answer (score 3):

Как пример, использовать svg:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

svg {
  overflow:visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg width="210" height="210" >
    <defs>
      <linearGradient id="grad1" x1="0" y1="1" x2="1" y2="0">
        <stop offset="0" stop-color="#8572a9" />
        <stop offset="1" stop-color="#787ece" />
      </linearGradient>
      <linearGradient id="grad2" xlink:href="#grad1" x1="1" y1="0" x2="0" y2="1"></linearGradient>
    </defs>
    <g fill="none">
      <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="50" fill="#2db687"/>
      
      
      
      <path d="M 95,5 C 230,5 230,195 95,195" stroke="url(#grad1)" stroke-width="5"></path>
      
      <circle cx="85" cy="5" r="5" fill="#787ece"/>      
      <circle cx="85" cy="5" r="10" stroke="#787ece" stroke-width="2"/>
      
      <circle cx="188" cy="140" r="8" fill="#7c7ac2"/>
      
      <circle cx="95" cy="195" r="8" fill="#8572a9"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```